# Couldnt read app configuration in PCF from bitbucket after upgrading spring & java versions

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry, spring-web, java-11

Pivotal Spring cloud config service doesnt work with Java 11 and spring boot 2.1.1.RELEASE and spring web: 5.1.3.RELEASE. I am getting "Error requesting access token". Any pointers to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that Spring Cloud Services is compatible with Spring Boot 2.1 or Java 11 at the time I write this.

> Note: Version 2.0.x of the SCS client dependencies is not compatible with Spring Boot 2.1.x.

https://docs.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/2-0/common/client-dependencies.html#including-dependencies

I can't provide you any guarantees, but it probably a safe bet that it will support both of those at some point in the future. For now, use Spring Boot 2.0 & Java 8 for best results, or at least to sanity check that things are working as you'd expect.

Hope that helps!